# Extrair dados de JSON, conforme exemplo

Tags: javascript, json, array

Tenho o seguinte objeto `JSON` que é retornado após consulta em banco de dados:

```
{
    data: {
        act: "3 ",
        searchType: "2",
        searchData: "33014421"
    },
    convicts: {
    count: 2,
    rows: [
            {
                idConvict: 7
            },
            {
                idConvict: 23
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Como extrair apenas os dados do campo `idConvict` de forma que me retorne um `array` `[7, 23]`?

Comment: poste o código do que já tentou fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com `map` no caminho `json.convicts.rows`, extraindo somente o valor de `idConvict` é gerado novo `array` `[7, 23]`, exemplo:

```js
const json = {
    data: {
        act: "3 ",
        searchType: "2",
        searchData: "33014421"
    },
    convicts: {
    count: 2,
    rows: [
            {
                idConvict: 7
            },
            {
                idConvict: 23
            }
        ]
    }
};



const ids = json.convicts.rows.map(x => {
  return x.idConvict;
});

console.log(ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let json = {
    data: {
        act: "3 ",
        searchType: "2",
        searchData: "33014421"
    },
    convicts: {
    count: 2,
    rows: [
            {
                idConvict: 7
            },
            {
                idConvict: 23
            }
        ]
    }
}

let ids_convict = json['convicts'].rows
    .forEach( e => {
        console.log(e.idConvict);
});



let outra_forma = json.convicts.rows
.forEach( e => {
    console.log(e.idConvict);
})


let mais_outra_forma = json.convicts.rows
    .forEach( e => console.log(e.idConvict));
```